# Learning LISP. Why does NIL print out after end of function using if statement

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Hi newbie here trying to learn lisp and im confused as to why lisp prints out NIL at the end of my output? Is there a way for it to not print NIL or is my if statement not set correctly.

```
(defun greater (x) 
  (if (> x 4) 
    (message "number is greater than 4")))
```

Get the result:

```
    [2]> (square 10)
    number greater than 4
    NIL
```

Comment: Does the result refer to the given code (the code defines the function `greater,` whereas in the result a function `square` is used)?

Answer (score 3):

All top level forms get printed by the Read-Eval-Print-Loop. Here is how to avoid it:

```
;;; make a main function
(defun main () 
  ;; all your program top level forms here!
  (values)) ; empty values return no value and the REPL will not print anything when your program terminates

;; call main
(main)
```

Of course in an interactive session you would like the result printed out so that you can enter `(+ 2 3)` and get `5` back without having to wrap it in a print statement.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the return value of your function. Your REPL (interactive evaluation) displays the result of each expression you enter. The result of calling your `greater` function is `NIL`.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I disagree with your edit. What do you mean by "interactive evaluation"?

Comment: The E in REPL stands for `eval` not for 'Interpreter'. Evaluation may use a compiler, as SBCL and CCL do. Here in this case CLISP has an interpreter-based REPL, but generally it is not the case.

Comment: A REPL is an interactive interpreter, no matter how it's implemented behind the scenes. The evaluation part of it is not interactive: You type your forms, send them to the interpreter for evaluation, and get a result back.

Comment: CCL/SBCL/... don't that. They takes the expression, compiles it and executes it. There is no Lisp Interpreter involved. The term interpreter in the Lisp context means executing Lisp forms directly (see McCarthy, Lisp 1). CCL/SBCL/... don't do that. They compile the expression and call the compiled code. In EVAL.  SBCL `* (lambda (x) x) -> #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X)) {1002B9076B}>   then (describe *)   ->  ...   [compiled function]   ....`  Thus the important part in the REPL is EVALUATION not how it is implemented.

Comment: @melpomene It's an interpreter only if you define 'interpreter' differently than computing people - and specifically lisp people -- generally do.  Under your definition the traditional 'ed;cc;a.out’ development process for C is also an interpreter.  It is sometimes entertaining to use wildly variant definitions but almost never helpful.